# Extract html table into R but skip specific elements (<br>) in one certain column that has three lines/rows, in a multi-page html

Tags: html, r, dataframe, html-table, html-tableextract

I want to load the table in a [link](http://www.hmdb.ca/metabolites?tf8=%E2%9C%93&filter=true&toxin=1&filter=true) into a dataframe in R.

The following script successfully extracts the table:

```
install.packages("htmltab")
library(htmltabl)
url <- "http://www.hmdb.ca/metabolites?utf8=✓&filter=true&toxin=1&filter=true"
hm_ext <- htmltab(url)
```

But here is the problem:

```
> head(hm_ext)
     HMDB ID CAS Number        Name FormulaAverage Mass Monoisotopic Mass                                           Biospecimen Location
2    HMDB000014264-18-6 Formic acid              CH2O246.025446.005479308 BloodBreast MilkCerebrospinal Fluid (CSF)FecesSalivaSweatUrine
3   HMDB0000228108-95-2      Phenol              C6H6O94.111294.041864814                                     BloodFecesSalivaSweatUrine
4 HMDB000059818496-25-8     Sulfide                    S32.06531.97207069                                                          Blood
5  HMDB00005997440-47-3    Chromium                 Cr51.996151.940511904                      BloodCerebrospinal Fluid (CSF)SalivaUrine
6  HMDB00006577440-50-8      Copper                  Cu63.54662.929601079                      BloodCerebrospinal Fluid (CSF)SalivaUrine
7  HMDB00006627782-41-4    Fluoride                  F18.998418.998403205                                               BloodSalivaUrine
```

The third column, i.e. `Formula Average Mass Monoisotopic Mass`, has three rows/values/lines and they are all mixed together and thus showing up as one continuous string. **I only want to extract the first line/row in this column OR somehow separate the three values from one another**.

Here is how the first cell of the third column looks like in the rendered html page:

[third column screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jmf9I.png)

Same thing happens if I use `XML::readHTMLTable`.

When I click on `Inspect Element` in Chrome, I can see such a structure for a cell in the `Formula Average Mass Monoisotopic Mass` column:

```
<td class="weight-value">CH<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub><br><br>46.0254<br>46.005479308</td>
```

[image -- please embed it. I do not have enough reputation to do that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPUQ7.png)

However, there are also other times when the second and third lines in this column are empty. Example:

```
<td class="weight-value">(C<sub>12</sub>H<sub>19</sub>NO<sub>19</sub>S<sub>3</sub>)nH<sub>2</sub>O<br><br><span class="wishart wishart-not-available">Not Available</span><br></td>
```

[image -- Inspect Element screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF0rY.png)

**So how can I extract the table from the given link but keep the structure of the third column readable and not mixed up?** And furthermore, is it possible to extract the tables in all pages without looping through the links for each separate page?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you need. But I think you want three seperate values for column no 3. Give us your expected output table to better answer this. However from first look I think you should look for `sub` command. See `?sub` and `?pattern`

Comment: If you take a look at the link using your browser, you will notice that column `FormulaAverage Mass Monoisotopic Mass` has exactly three values each in a separate line. When loading the html table into R, all of the lines get coerced into one string.

Comment: What link? I can see two images which have more then 3 values.

Comment: I am interested in only keeping the string that is on the first line, but if keeping only the first one is not possible, then I want to have three but at least separated in a way that is human-readable and not all mixed up and confused. In the current state it is not possible to use `sub` because it is not possible to understand how the three lines are separated, i.e. they have no separator at all, the separator is `""` which makes it impossible to retrieve the original values.

Comment: The link is in the first chunk of code in my post. `url <- "http://www.hmdb.ca/metabolites?utf8=✓&filter=true&toxin=1&filter=true"`

Comment: You have this: `CH2O246.025446.005479308` you can use pattern as the `dot` and seperate them.

Comment: @SamAct No. That is incorrect. The `dot` comes from the decimal number on the second and third lines and there is no way to find out what the original value. Why? Here's an example: take `CH2O246.025446.005479308`, what was the value on the first line? Was it `CH2O`? Or was it `CH2O2`? Or was it `CH2O24`? `dot` is meaningless here, it belongs to the decimal number and is not a separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the approach could be

```r
library(rvest)
library(qdapRegex)
library(XML)

#read webpage
htm_data <- read_html("http://www.hmdb.ca/metabolites?tf8=%E2%9C%93&filter=true&toxin=1&filter=true") 

#convert above webpage's table into a dataframe
df <- html_table(html_nodes(htm_data, "table"))[[1]]

#cleanup data in the required column
df[, 4] <- unlist(lapply(rm_between(xml_find_all(htm_data, "//table/tbody/tr/td[4]"), 
                                    ">", 
                                    "<br><br>", extract=TRUE), 
                         function(x) gsub("<.*?>", "", x[[1]])))
```

which gives

```
> head(df)
    HMDB ID  CAS Number        Name Structure FormulaAverage Mass Monoisotopic Mass
1    HMDB000014264-18-6 Formic acid        NA                                 CH2O2
2   HMDB0000228108-95-2      Phenol        NA                                 C6H6O
3 HMDB000059818496-25-8     Sulfide        NA                                     S
4  HMDB00005997440-47-3    Chromium        NA                                    Cr
5  HMDB00006577440-50-8      Copper        NA                                    Cu
6  HMDB00006627782-41-4    Fluoride        NA                                     F
                                            Biospecimen Location
1 BloodBreast MilkCerebrospinal Fluid (CSF)FecesSalivaSweatUrine
2                                     BloodFecesSalivaSweatUrine
3                                                          Blood
4                      BloodCerebrospinal Fluid (CSF)SalivaUrine
5                      BloodCerebrospinal Fluid (CSF)SalivaUrine
6                                               BloodSalivaUrine
```

Comment: Very clever. Thanks a lot. I wouldn't have been able to figure this out in any way by myself. Great answer. Everything works perfectly. I only receive this warning: `In stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(text.var, pattern) :
  argument is not an atomic vector; coercing` but I assume it is nothing important, because I do not see anything wrong in the extracted data table.

Comment: Glad that it helped! Btw I am not very sure about the cause of error message mentioned in your comment as I can't reproduce it but I guess you may want to try `stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(text.var[[1]], pattern)`.